# Can't get stqdm() to work in a for loop in a streamlit app

Tags: python, web-scraping, streamlit, tqdm

I've been trying to incorporate the `stqdm` status bar [in the dev branch of my streamlit app](https://github.com/jrodriguez5909/RecipeScraper/tree/development) and can't get around the error message below. I've wrapped the `for` loop in the `df_create()` function in `main.py` with the `stqdm()` method but I don't think this is how this is meant to be used. Here's an excerpt of the function showing what I've done:

```
def create_df(recipes):
    """
    Description:
    Creates one df with all recipes and their ingredients
    Arguments:
    * recipes: list of recipe URLs provided by user
    Comments:
    Note that ingredients with qualitative amounts e.g., "scheutje melk", "snufje zout" have been ommitted from the ingredient list
    """
    df_list = []

    for recipe in stqdm(range(len(recipes))):
        scraper = scrape_me(recipe)
        recipe_details = replace_measurement_symbols(scraper.ingredients())

        recipe_name = recipe.split("https://www.hellofresh.nl/recipes/", 1)[1]
        recipe_name = recipe_name.rsplit('-', 1)[0]
        print("Processing data for "+ recipe_name +" recipe.")
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Any help would be appeciated!

---

[image]

Comment: The `from recipe_scrapers import scrape_me` is from [this github](https://github.com/hhursev/recipe-scrapers)? - if so, try to post an issue in the linked github - probably is a unhandled website - see the [available scrapers](https://github.com/hhursev/recipe-scrapers#scrapers-available-for).

Comment: Also, try to print the value of `recipe` - https://github.com/jrodriguez5909/RecipeScraper/blob/development/main.py#L66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of the current script, this has nothing to do with stqdm or even streamlit.

You might have a typo that makes you iterate over the index of the list instead of its elements.
Replace `range(len(recipes))` with `recipes` or replace the name of the index with `index` and go with `recipes[index]`.

You should probably be able to reproduce this with the code below in a script ran directly with python.

```py
from recipe_scrapers import scrape_me

recipes = ["https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/158968/spinach-and-feta-turkey-burgers/"]

# You should rather do: `for recipe in stqdm(recipes):`
for recipe in range(len(recipes)):
   scrape_me(recipe)
```

On another note, you might have been able to find this by yourself by trying to produce a more minimal example.

Comment: Thanks! I overcomplicated things since "for recipe in stqdm(recipes):" ended up working!